# WAMP Sub domain routing with laravel

Tags: apache, laravel, wamp, laravel-5.1, wampserver

I am using laravel 5.1 & WAMP server 2.5.

I have my domain like 'www.example.com' which is pointing to the root.
where else I have a subdomain like 'admin.examle.com'.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'app', 'middleware' => 'authentication'], function () {
        Route::get('home', ['as' => 'app.home', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@home']);
    });
```

I have added virtual hosts on httpd-vhosts.conf as below:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/app"
    ServerAlias app.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

But as app is not an actual folder in my www folder it is showing internal server error. Can anyone help with this ?? I need to use subdomains for the same.

Comment: DocumentRoot must be "C:/wamp/www/app/public"

Comment: @BilalIqbal but I have configured it as http://_SERVER_IP_/app, I am not sure but the pointing is to app which is a virtual folder, Now the between <VirtualHost *> </VirtualHost> tags it should be physical path I suppose, so in my case it is not working

Answer (score 0):

- Check your DocumentRoot, all Laravel applications should be pointed towards **public** directory, where the index.php file is located
- Check your hosts file *(I'm a Windows user myself)*, this file allows web browsers to point domains towards specific IPs (For instance, using mysubdomain.myapp.local). To read more about hosts file http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/